# c# 7 when using generics for method parameter I get The constraints for type parameter 'U' of method must match the constraints for the interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to create an interface and a concrete implementation where the Interface is a generic type and one of the methods has a generic parameter.

I want to keep the GetPagedList method parameter, resourceParams, generic so I can pass in different resourceParams objects for different implementations of the Interface.

When using the code shown below, I am getting the error;

> The constraints for type parameter 'U' of method 'ShippingServicesRepository.GetPagedList(U)' must match the constraints for the type parameter 'U' of interface method IBaseRepository.GetPagedList(U). Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead

Here is my interface;

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> 
{
    bool Save();
    bool Exists(int recordId);
    bool MarkForDeletion(int recordId);
    PagedList<T> GetPagedList<U>(U resourceParams) where U : class;
    T Get(int id);
    void Add(T record);
    void Update(T record);
}
```

And here is my implementation;

```
public class ShippingServicesRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> 
{

    //                      /--- GetPagedList is what is throwing the error
    //                      |
    public PagedList<T> GetPagedList<U> (U resourceParams) where U : ShippingServicesResourceParameters
    {
        try
        {

            var collectionBeforePaging =
                _manifestContext.ShippingServices
                .ApplySort(resourceParams.OrderBy, _propertyMappingService.GetPropertyMapping<ShippingServicesDto, ShippingServices>());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceParams.SearchQuery))
            {
                var searchQueryForWhereClause = resourceParams.SearchQuery.Trim().ToLowerInvariant();
                collectionBeforePaging = collectionBeforePaging
                    .Where(a => a.ReferenceId.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchQueryForWhereClause));
            }
            collectionBeforePaging = collectionBeforePaging
                .Where(d => d.DeleteFlag == resourceParams.DeleteFlag);

            return (dynamic)PagedList<ShippingServices>.Create(collectionBeforePaging,
                resourceParams.PageNumber,
                resourceParams.PageSize);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError(500, "ShippingServices Filter [{FILTER}]", resourceParams);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Add(T record)
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool Exists(int recordId)
    {
        ...
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool MarkForDeletion(int recordId)
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Update(T record)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Here is my ShippingServicesResourceParameters class

```
public class ShippingServicesResourceParameters : BaseResourceParameters
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the BaseResourceParameters class inherited by ShippingServicesResourceParameters

```
public class BaseResourceParameters
{
    private int _pageSize;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageSize;
        }
        set
        {
            _pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value;
            if (value == 0)
            {
                _pageSize = 10; // set a default size
            }
        }
    }

    public int MaxPageSize { get; set; } = 20;
    public bool DeleteFlag { get; set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; } = "Id";
    public string Fields { get; set; }
}
```

It I don't add the "where U : ShippingServicesResourceParameters" to the method signature in the concrete implementation and "where U : class" in the Interface, I get a "Cannot convert from Method Group to String..." error from the first use of the resourceParams variable in the concrete implementation. (at ".ApplySort(resourceParams.OrderBy")

What am I missing here?

Comment: Any reason for all the generics when you're using concrete classes in the method?

Comment: I believe the issue is that this `where U : ShippingServicesResourceParameters` needs to be `where U : ShippingServicesResourceParameters, class`, but I can't test that right now.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud You can't specify class with another class constraint.

Comment: Please make a repro that is about one twentieth the size of this repro. There's a HUGE amount of completely irrelevant cruft to wade through here.

Comment: The error you reported is different than the one in your title. Also, when does the error occur? When the method is called? If so, please show us the code that calls it.

Comment: @MarkDavies This is one concrete implementation of several that will implement the same interface but will apply to different repository class.

Comment: You are *required* to make the generic constraints match when implementing an interface. Your implementation accepts *less* than the interface requires, and therefore is not legal.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.  What are the constraints for the method you're writing?  What are the constraints for the interface implementation you want it to implement?  Are they identical? (Hint, they're not, the error message is telling you as much.)

Comment: It seems like you are trying to make something *generic* that inherently isn't.

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what "ApplySort" is, and that's apparently where the error is.  **You have to give us enough information to understand the problem if you want a sensible answer**.  Help us help you.  Make a **minimal** repro that *clearly* demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also, it is a really bad idea to make a property `OrderBy` that is the same name as one of the LINQ query operators which is probably in scope. That's likely the source of the problem.

Comment: I get the error by highlighting over the word "resourceParams" in the line ".ApplySort(resourceParams.OrderBy". You don't have to run the code to see it.

Comment: Looks like you syntax of method declaration should be the same in Interface and Class. Try to prepare interface for BaseResourceParameters, and use it in both cases.

Comment: No, we have to be *you* with *your debugging setup* to see it!

Comment: But long story short: you cannot put a constraint that is *stronger* than `class` on the implementation, which means that the body of the method *cannot* know that `U` has a property `OrderBy`.  If you want to make that constraint then *it has to be on the interface too*.

Comment: @EricLippert - Sorry for any confusion. The error is syntactical with how I am trying to pass the generic for the resourceParams parameter. It shows in VS2017 in the editor without running the code. I am just trying to figure out how to pass a generic value as a parameter into this concrete implementation.

Comment: @EricLippert - I added the constraint as an attempt to get past the initial error, which was the "Cannot convert from Method Group to String...". So perhaps there is another solution for that than using a constraint on the interface.

Comment: Do not **randomly change constraints hoping that they will fix the problem**.  That's not a solid engineering approach. Understand the problem *first* and *then* fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's do **what you should have done in the first place** and make a minimal program that demonstrates the problem:

```
interface I 
{
    void M<U>(U u) where U : class;
}
class D 
{
    public void O() {}
}
class C : I
{
    public void M<U>(U u) where U : D
    {
        u.O();
    }
}
```

This is an error because C does not implement I.  It does not implement I because:

```
I i = new C();
i.M<Giraffe>(new Giraffe());
```

Now we have a giraffe passed to `C.M<Giraffe>(Giraffe)` but `C.M<U>` requires that U is D.  So that's illegal.

We cannot fix it like this:

```
    public void M<U>(U u) where U : class
    {
        u.O();
    }
```

because now we could have `D.O()` called on a receiver of type Giraffe.

Therefore we have to fix it like this:

```
interface I 
{
    void M<U>(U u) where U : D;
}
class D 
{
    public void O() {}
}
class C : I
{
    public void M<U>(U u) where U : D
    {
        u.O();
    }
}
```

And now we're all good.

You are **required** to make the implementation constraints match the interface constraints, just like you're required to meet every other requirement imposed by the interface. **Interfaces are contracts**. You have to fulfill your end of the bargain.

I note that this is what the error message says: you have to match the constraints, and you're not doing so. Pay attention to the error messages; most of the time they tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I appreciate the time you put into formulating your answer.

Comment: @EiEiGuy: You're welcome. If that's not yet clear, think about it like this.  Suppose you had `interface I { void M(Animal a); }` You cannot then say, oh, hey, I want to implement `I` but have `M` only take `Giraffe`.  The contract of `I` is *`M` can take any `Animal`* and if you want to implement `I`, that's a requirement.  In your case the requirement you put on the method is *`U` can be constructed with any reference type*. You can't then say "well, in *my* implementation `U` can only be constructed with `ShippingServicesResourceParameters` descendant types, for the same reason.